# shell command psql vs php pg_query performance

Tags: php, shell, psql, postgresql-9.4, pg-query

I have doubts about the speed of a query in postgres.

I run this query in psql (shell):

```
"EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from historial where empresa = 2";
```

The result is:

```
Execution time: 125.064 ms
```

Then i run the same query with PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE empresa = 2";
pg_query($db, $sql);
```

The result is:

```
Execution time: 1325.792 ms
```

which it is the real time ?

Answer (score 0):

The **second** one is the real time of the actual `SELECT` execution.

The first one is only the time it took to *analyze* the query.